# Livechat API - Queue time

Tags: php, date, time, livechat

I'm trying to GET how long the longest visitor has been in queue using the livechat API.

This below is my code:

```
 <?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Stockholm');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.livechatinc.com/visitors?state=queued");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERNAME, "XXXXXX");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-API-Version:2'));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$string = json_decode($result); // decoding the result
$queued = $string->queue_start_time; // getting the queue start time
$longest = min(array($queued)); // getting the smallest unix time of all visitors
$date = date('U', time()); //getting current time
$queuetime = abs($date-$longest); //calculating the difference between current time and the visitors queue time.
echo intval(date('i',$acttime))." min"; //displaying the visitor queue time in minutes
?>
```

Why am I not getting this to work? It keeps returning "0 min".

Comment: Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Have you tried to `var_dump(json_decode($result))`? According to the php documentation and according to LiveChat API documentation it will return you array of visitors (which will be stdClasses). I would then loop through all of them and tried to look for the minimum.

Comment: it could be ssl problem

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Project is abandoned unfortunately, questions asked in august 2015.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code and let me know how it works:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Stockholm');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.livechatinc.com/visitors?state=queued");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, LOGIN . ":" . API_KEY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-API-Version:2'));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$visitors = json_decode($result); // decoding the result

$queueTime = array();
foreach ($visitors as $key => $value)
{
// getting the queue start time for all queued visitors
$queueTime[] = $value->queue_start_time;
}
$longest = min($queueTime); // getting the smallest unix time of all visitors
$date = date('U', time()); //getting current time
$queuetime = abs($date - $longest); //calculating the difference between current time and the visitors queue time.
$queuetimeMinutes = floor($queuetime / 60);
$queuetimeSeconds = $queuetime % 60;
echo "$queuetimeMinutes min and $queuetimeSeconds seconds";  //displaying the visitor queue time in minutes

?>
```

Cheers Adam

Comment: please highlight what you've changed and what you think the problem is.

Comment: @iblamefish as you see, the code has changed a lot. We did our best to provide the working solution but I believe it was faulty to start with and that's the main cause of the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Project is abandoned unfortunately, questions asked in august 2015.